# how to convert date format in aqua data studio

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have using aqua data studio to run my query from sql server 2005. The error show when i run my sql.
This is my sql

```
select TO_CHAR(entered,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DATE_D  from customer
```

Comment: try this link: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
select 
  convert(varchar(10),entered,103) AS DATE_D 
from 
  customer
```

This will get you the format `dd/mm/yyyy`. For other date format see this [link](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

**EDIT**

If you want a parameter for date. Then it dependes on if you want to do the comparisen on the date or the converted varchar. Here is too examples:

```
DECLARE @DATE_D VARCHAR(20)
SET @DATE_D='01-01-2011'

SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    select 
        convert(varchar,entered,103) AS DATE_D,
        customer.entered
    from 
        customer 
) as T
WHERE T.DATE_D=@DATE_D
```

Or with datetime like this:

```
DECLARE @DATE_D DATETIME
SET @DATE_D='2011-01-01'

select 
    convert(varchar,entered,103) AS DATE_D,
    customer.entered
from 
    customer 
WHERE
    customer.entered=@DATE_D
```

Comment: Thank you very much Arion. But i have one more question. How to create the parameter for date?.because i also have try but the error was show.This is my sql.                                             select 
  convert(varchar,entered,103) AS DATE_D 
from 
  customer

where &DATE_D

Comment: Updated the answer. @Amin : remember to upvote if you think the answer is good. It gives us all warm-fuzzy feelings